# how to keep some folder public

Tags: git, github

I am new to Github

I want to create a core PHP folder that be used for future website development

So, In each new project, I will use the core app

now I want when I change the core app in every website, the affected files commited to the master core and other cores

how can I achieve that ?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules should be the way